# Problema para cadastrar Usuário pelo android erro na acentuação

Tags: android, web-service, url, acentuação, volley

To enviando os dados por URL para meu webservice se eu colocar o caminho pelo navegador web exemplo no Chrome:

> meuwebservice/inserirusu/á

ja pelo android ele tem essa saida

> meuwebservice/inserirusu/%C3%A1

Meu metodo

```
private void inserir(final String edicao) {  edicao = "á"
showProgressDialog();

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
        Const.URL_EDITAR_TRABALHADOR+URLEncoder.encode(edicao, "UTF-8"), new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        if(response.equal("Alterado"){
           hideProgressDialog();
           finish();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        hideProgressDialog();

    }
});

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

}

O problema esta no

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Const.URL_EDITAR_TRABALHADOR+URLEncoder.encode(edicao, "UTF-8"), new Response.Listener<String>()
```

Tenho essa saída do android `meuwebservice/inserirusu/%C3%A1`

Comment: E o problema onde está? Especifique melhor sua pergunta

Comment: Aqui não é lugar para perguntar sobre esporte :D (http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)